# Is modern warfare inherently linked to sexual violence?

Tags: war

Recently any conflict I'm reading up on has a record of sexual violence going with it, so I want to know if it's really an inherent aspect of war? Examples of war NOT being accompanied with sexual violence would reveal that sexual violence isn't necessarily part of war in modern history.

Dates under consideration : 1970 to present day.

Limited to wars where there was on-ground presence/movement of troops in civilian areas (and where hostilities weren't scheduled only at designated battlefields, if such a thing ever happened!). Excluding wars where there is no opportunity for sexual violence (e.g. naval or aerial bombardment)

In case anyone wants clarification on "major", how's this:
At least 50 victims in total, sexual violence being rape and/or genital mutilation. During hostilities and in first year after end of hostilities if foreign occupation. Victims include prisoners of war, refugees, resident populations where hostilities took place.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79045/discussion-on-question-by-nikhilvj-is-warfare-linked-to-sexual-violence-in-the-m).

Comment: Any war involving low discipline troops occupying enemy territory will result in some degree of sexual violence. And even wars involving relatively higher discipline troops result in the same, as you noted in your question. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - see the comments & the revision history; OP has tried multiple times to ask this question.  I think he is looking to confirm your statement. It would be interesting to see if there is any research that analyzes the impact of troop disciple and other factors on the rate of sexual violence, but OP is just asking for the evidence to confirm or deny the hypothesis.  (@nikhilvj, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: In my view the question ought to get downvoted into oblivion and closed. The question reads like: here's my ludicrous thesis; please find me proof amongst the side shows of history. (And that might have flied, if the US, Russia, and others had not had such a poor record with restraining soldiers in the past few decades. But they didn't, hence the ludicrous.)

Answer (score 9):

The most obvious candidate that leaps to mind is the [Falklands War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falklands_War). I can't remember there being any allegations of major sexual violence from either side.

Comment: How about the War of Jenkin's Ear?

Comment: @Oldcat it's about 200 years too early, the question asked for wars from 1950 to present day.